# Range reference using "Cells" references

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using long variables to denote columns and rows. When I try to specify a range by the type `sheetname.range(cells(i,j), cells(i+1, j+1))` I'm getting a Method `Range of Object Worksheet failed` error.

Any ideas on how to use a range when using long variables as cell references?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sheetname.Range(sheetname.Cells(i,j), sheetname.Cells(i+1, j+1))
```

An unqualified `Cells()` will always refer to the active sheet.

I'd rather use:

```
sheetname.Cells(i,j).Resize(2,2)
```